# refresh page after event receiver item updated

Tags: event-receivers, redirect, itemupdated

I'm trying to refresh the page after the event `itemupdated` is fired.
I've tried at the end of `itemupdated` without success

```
 properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
 properties.RedirectUrl = "http://www.google.be/";
```

I tried too this but no result

```
SPUtility.Redirect("http://www.google.be", SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, HttpContext.Current);
```

And finally in `itemupdating`, I've tried

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
context.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.be");
```

I've tried the proposed solution but still doesn't work

I've added the synchronous in Element.xml

```
<Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
```

and this line in my itemupdated

```
SPUtility.Redirect("http://www.google.be", SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, HttpContext.Current);
```

But nothing happened

I've no more ideas on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the solution lies [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3453a76c-304a-4520-a5b1-0a6b76ddc43d/in-a-sharepoint-site-2010-i-am-trying-to-redirect-to-a-custom-page-from-the-itemupdated-event-with?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious).

You need to ensure the `ItemUpdated` event runs synchronously rather than async.

The `ItemUpdated` event by default will run after the page has already posted back and does not have a connection to the HttpContext of the firing page.

`ItemUpdating` should have a connection, but marking it as synchronous might help.